# Generating service interfaces from legacy WSDL for using inside CoreWCF

Tags: asp.net-core, wsdl, svcutil.exe, wsdl.exe, corewcf

We have a legacy WCF app (soap-based) that had been written by ASP.NET Framework 4.6. We are upgrading the app to ASP.NET Core using CoreWCF package. There are tons of different soap methods in our application. We also have some clients that consume our soap services and because of that, we have to upgrade our application without any "Breaking Changes" on our WSDL.

Is there any way to generate service interfaces from an old WSDL for using in the new service app? In other words, are there some tools (like svcutil.exe or wsdl.exe) that generate server interfaces for using in an ASP.NET Core server app?